# Cron doesn't run bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have cron

> SHELL=/bin/bash
>
> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
>
> ```
> * * * * * root  /usr/bin/flock -xn /var/lock/script.lock -c '/bin/bash /root/Dropbox/1.sh'
> ```

my 1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash -l 

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin 

x=1
while [ $x -le 3 ] 
do 
URL=$(head -n 1 /root/Dropbox/query.txt) 
lynx -dump  $URL | egrep '^http' > /root/Dropbox/urls.txt 
x=$(( $x + 1 )) 
done
```

Bash as default

# echo $SHELL

/bin/bash

Why cron doesn't run 1.sh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove "root" in line crontab line:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/flock -xn /var/lock/script.lock -c '/bin/bash /root/Dropbox/1.sh'
```

If you need root rights put in crontab of root user.
With "root" you will also find error in syslog or messages logs.

And of course be sure the **cron daemon is running**: ps -ef | grep cron

ADD:
I've tested it with simple touch a file (on ubuntu):
contab line:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/flock -xn /var/lock/script.lock -c '/bin/bash ~/1.sh'
```

1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /tmp/hallo
```

ADD: (looking at lynx command)
A version of 1.sh Script it works for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

x=1
while [ $x -le 3 ]
do
URL="http://www.subir.com/lynx.html"
lynx -dump  $URL | egrep '.*\. http' > urls.txt
x=$(( $x + 1 ))
done
```

I changed the regEx on egrep. Your output of lynx may be different (other version of lynx). And I used a fixed test URL (lynx man page). The urls.txt will be filled. Script is triggered by cron. The while will have no effect noting in loop logic will be change on next run.

```
stephan@coppi:~$ more urls.txt 
   1. http://lynx.isc.org/current/index.html
   2. http://lynx.isc.org/current/lynx2-8-8/lynx_help/lynx_help_main.html
   3. http://lynx.isc.org/current/lynx2-8-8/lynx_help/Lynx_users_guide.html
   4. http://lynx.isc.org/lynx2.8.7/index.html
   5. http://lynx.isc.org/lynx2.8.7/lynx2-8-7/lynx_help/lynx_help_main.html
   6. http://lynx.isc.org/lynx2.8.7/lynx2-8-7/lynx_help/Lynx_users_guide.html
   7. http://lynx.isc.org/mirrors.html
   8. http://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/lynx-dev/
   9. http://lynx.isc.org/signatures.html
  10. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flynx.isc.org%2Findex.html
```

Comment: cron daemon is running. I put in 1.sh cat, grep or wget - cron run 1.sh  I think something wrong with variable $URL or $x, may be cron doesn't understand it correctly. I tested without root in cron - no running.

Comment: If cron has started the 1.sh script the job is done for cron. The while loop in 1.sh is also generally ok. Not sure about the URL and lynx line. Can you run another script (easy on) via cron? And can you run the 1.sh script manually without errors?

Comment: yes I run script manually without problem in console. Without lynx and without $URL, $x - it work from cron

Comment: sounds crazy. Can you send some lines (2-4) of your query.txt than I can debug it, if you want.